# BindingSource and DataGridView default current position

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

Does the BindingSource have an automatic default current position?  I have an event handler on CurrentCellChanged event and it seems to be firing twice. I am programatically setting the starting position using the BindingSource Find method at that works but before im setting that starting position, the CurrentCellChanged is already firing and the initial selected cell is column 0 row 0.  When you create a BindingSource is it already setting the Current property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN for [DataGridView.CurrentCell Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx) mentions the default CurrentCell property value is the first cell in the first row (or null if there are no cells in the DGV).

Setting this default would fire your CurrentCellChanged event, explaining why you're seeing the event for cell 0, 0.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure what you are seeing is the DataGridView firing its various selection events (CurrentCellChanged, SelectionChanged etc...) during the databinding process. Because you have attached an eventhandler to one of these events it fires.

The way around this is to attach an eventhandler to the DataGridView's DataBindingComplete and attach your CurrentCellChanged handler there.

```
// Attach the event in the form's constructor
this.dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += new DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventHandler(dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete);

// And in the eventhandler, attach to the CurrentCellChanged event.
void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.CurrentCellChanged += new EventHandler(dataGridView1_CurrentCellChanged);
}
```